# LARAVEL : return all post has last comment base on current login user

Tags: sql, laravel

Query
GET all POST of USER

```
$result = DB::table('tasks as t')->select('*' , 't.created_by as task_creator' , 't.task_id as task_id' , 't.created_at as task_created')
                ->join('task_assign as ta', 'ta.task_id', '=', 't.task_id')
                ->join('users as u' , 'u.id' , '=' , 't.created_by')
                ->join('task_categories as tcc' , 'tcc.category_id' , '=' , 't.category_id')
                ->leftJoin('task_comments as tc' , 'tc.task_id' , '=' , 't.task_id')
                ->where("ta.user_id" ,  Auth::user()->id)
                ->where("t.status" , 'A')
                ->where("t.task_status" , '!=' , 'D')
                ->orderBy('tc.date_added' ,'DESC')
                ->orderBy('t.task_id' ,'DESC')
                ->get();
```

Get all a post that user is last commented

```
 # SET STATUS BASED ON USERS
$c = [];
$group = [];
foreach ($newArray as $key => $row) {
   # check if user is the last comment
   $check = DB::table('task_comments as tc')->select('*')
                  ->where("tc.task_id" , $row->task_id)
                  ->orderBy('tc.task_comments_id' ,'DESC')
                  ->get()->first();

  if (!empty($check)) {
      if ($check->user_id == Auth::user()->id) {
          $c[] = $check->user_id;
               $group['I'][$key] = $row;  
      }
   }
}
```

is their a way that i can remove the loop
and get all post if post last comment is the current login user.

Answer (score 0):

What I use for that is QueryBuilder macro. Add this script in your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`

```
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        Builder::macro('whereLatest', function ($table, $parentRelatedColumn) {
            return $this->where($table . '.id', function ($sub) use ($table, $parentRelatedColumn) {
                $sub->select('id')
                    ->from($table . ' AS t1')
                    ->whereColumn('t1.' . $parentRelatedColumn, $table . '.' . $parentRelatedColumn)
                    ->latest()
                    ->take(1);
            });
        });
    }
```

Than you can use:

```
Auth::user()->whereHas('posts', function($q) {
    $q->whereLatest('posts_table_name', 'user_id');
});
```

Comment: return $this->hasMany('App\TaskAssign','user_id','id')
->join('tasks','tasks.task_id','=','task_assign.task_id')
->with(['get_comments'])
->whereHas('get_comments',function($q) {
    $table = 'task_comments';
    $parentRelatedColumn = 'user_id';
      return $q->where($table . '.task_comments_id', function ($sub) use ($table, $parentRelatedColumn) {
        $sub->select('task_comments.task_comments_id')
        ->from($table . ' AS t1')
        ->whereColumn('t1.' . $parentRelatedColumn, $table . '.' . $parentRelatedColumn)
        ->latest('date_added')
        ->take(1);
})
});

Comment: Did you update posts_table_name and user_id `$q->whereLatest('posts_table_name', 'user_id');` here?

Comment: yes i update it see my new explanation on bottom. if you can help me in raw sql pls need you help in this thank you.